# Turning If / else if / else into Switch / Case in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, case

I'm refining my understanding of arrays and if / else if / else statements.  I want to see if I can convert my if / else if / else statements into Switch / Case.  What's the best way to go about this?  I have heard that Switch / Case is much more efficient when dealing with a broader range of choices.
Should I stay with the if / else? or is there a way to convert my choices into Switch Case?
Here is the example I am making for them and in the code.

```
{
        int []  acct = new int [3];

        acct[0] = 8675309;
        acct[1] = 8675310;
        acct[2] = 8675311;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your account number");
        int myacct = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //int myacct = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());<--This works too
        if (myacct == acct[0])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        }
        else if (myacct == acct[1])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        }
        else if (myacct == acct[2])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you don't have access");
        }

        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        string[] names = new string[3] { "Jenny", "Roberto", "Sally" };
        /*  This shows them how to tighten the code up compaired to the technique we used above
        names[0] = "Jenny";
        names[1] = "Roberto";
        names[2] = "Sally";
        */

        //I'd like to make the following code into a Switch and Case type statement instead of using else if.


        /*
        if (myacct == acct [0] && name == "Jenny")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome "+names[0] + "!");
        }


        else if (myacct == acct[1] && name == "Roberto")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome Roberto" + names[1] + "!");
        }
        else if (myacct == acct[2] && name == "Sally")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome Sally" + names[2] + "!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account number and Names do not match");
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  its not clear

Comment: How can you teach someone something that you don't know about?

Comment: but you know that switch/case is for constant?

Comment: That's why I'm asking.  Can I change the if else code into a switch case statement?  I'm trying to learn so I can show alternate ways to do the same basic code.

Comment: You might want to read through Microsoft's documentation on [C# switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Comment: Perhaps [this case-label reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#case-labels) might be helpful?

Comment: whats wrong with you guys, trying to solve this and got downvotes...

Comment: The code might not become clearer if you refactor it to using switch but you can do `switch (myacct) { case int a when a == acct[0]: ...` and so on. Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WSqXeX - However, you might benefit more from a completely different approach altogether, but it's hard to tell from simple examples.

Comment: Thank you so much Lasse, I think I'm close ```switch (myacct, name)
            {

                case int a when a == acct[0]:
                case string b when b == names[0]:
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + names[0] + "!");
                    break;

            }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look at it this way:

- `switch(value)` declares coder's intention to make branching decisions based on `value`
- `if`-`else if` can have arbitrary conditions
- there is a possibility of an accidental `if` instead of `else if` in the middle of the chain that can lead to either bugs or misunderstanding of the original coder's intent.

Up to C# 6.0 `switch`'s `case` [could only operate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement) with constant values, which means that with a chain of `if`-`else if` being more flexible you might have some difficulty directly translating it into a `switch` in C# 6.0 and below.

Starting with C# 7.0 a more flexible [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) was introduced, making it possible to use non-constant patterns.

In C# 8.0 there are also [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement), [property and tuple patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#property-patterns) that can make the code much more readable and concise in some cases.